# MongoEngine distinct() filtering and EmbeddedDocument

Tags: mongoengine

Recently, maybe after a software upgrade, I've encountered a problem: distinct() filtering now returns a dictionary collection rather then a EmbeddedDocument collection. Mean while direct traverse of objects works as expected.

Here is the piece of code, maybe not stripped down but rather simple. This is a simple product catalog with features for functionality like filtering by features and so on:

```
from mongoengine import *


class FeatureInfo(Document):
    title = StringField()


class ProductFeature(EmbeddedDocument):
    featureInfo = ReferenceField(FeatureInfo)
    value = StringField()

    def eq(a, b):
        return a.featureInfo.title == b.featureInfo.title and a.value == b.value


class Product(Document):
    title = StringField()
    features = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(ProductFeature))


def populate():
    producer_feature_info = FeatureInfo("Producer")
    producer_feature_info.save()

    screen_size_feature_info = FeatureInfo("Screen size")
    screen_size_feature_info.save()

    iphone_producer_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=producer_feature_info, value="Apple")
    iphone_screen_size_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=screen_size_feature_info, value="4 inch")

    iphone = Product(title="iPhone 5S")
    iphone.features.append(iphone_producer_feature)
    iphone.features.append(iphone_screen_size_feature)
    iphone.save()

    galaxy_producer_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=producer_feature_info, value="Samsung")
    galaxy_screen_size_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=screen_size_feature_info, value="5 inch")

    galaxy = Product(title="Galaxy S4")
    galaxy.features.append(galaxy_producer_feature)
    galaxy.features.append(galaxy_screen_size_feature)
    galaxy.save()

    galaxy_producer_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=producer_feature_info, value="Samsung")
    galaxy_screen_size_feature = ProductFeature(featureInfo=screen_size_feature_info, value="4 inch")

    galaxy = Product(title="Galaxy S2")
    galaxy.features.append(galaxy_producer_feature)
    galaxy.features.append(galaxy_screen_size_feature)
    galaxy.save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect('test')
    populate()

    products = Product.objects()

    print "\n".join(map(lambda p: p.title + " [" + ", ".join(map(lambda f: f.featureInfo.title + " = " + f.value, p.features)) + "]", products))

    print "\nProduct features"

    features = []

    for product in products:
        print product.title
        for feature in product.features:
            if feature not in features:
                features.append(feature)
            print feature.__class__.__name__

    print "\nUnique features"

    for feature in features:
        print feature.featureInfo.title + " = " + feature.value + " (" + feature.__class__.__name__ + ")"

    print "\nDistinct features"

    features = products.distinct("features")

    for feature in features:
        print feature.__class__.__name__
```

Here is the output:

```
python test.py 
iPhone 5S [Producer = Apple, Screen size = 4 inch]
Galaxy S4 [Producer = Samsung, Screen size = 5 inch]
Galaxy S2 [Producer = Samsung, Screen size = 4 inch]

Product features
iPhone 5S
ProductFeature
ProductFeature
Galaxy S4
ProductFeature
ProductFeature
Galaxy S2
ProductFeature
ProductFeature

Unique features
Producer = Apple (ProductFeature)
Screen size = 4 inch (ProductFeature)
Producer = Samsung (ProductFeature)
Screen size = 5 inch (ProductFeature)

Distinct features
BaseDict
BaseDict
BaseDict
BaseDict
```

I found such a question on StackOverflow but there was issue with MongoEngine 0.8.3 and ok in 0.8.4. I've followed it and upgraded but with no effect.